# Can you use three quotes in a sentence by including a quote within a quote. Eg "' xxx ' xxx"

Tags: speech, quotation-marks

Can you use three quotes in a sentence by including a quote within a quote? Eg "' xxx ' xxx"

Comment: It might help to have a clearer example of the intended use.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the nominated duplicate answers this. Yes, just alternate the type of quote-mark for each "quoted quote". If you start with two, the quote within is contained in single-quotes, and if you need another level in that, use doubles again. Note that spaces should only come immediately outside quote marks, not inside, and only if the space does not have a quote character of some type on both sides. Thus your example would be `“‘xxx’ xxx”`.